# Couldn't connect to host (Error 7) in multi-threaded CURL mipsel-linux mipsel multicore architect

Tags: linux, multithreading, curl, libcurl, mips32

I'm trying to run [this sample](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multithread.html) on an mipsel-based product board. My OS configuration is OK & there is no problem in single-thread mode, but when I want to try it in multi-threaded manner, **curl_earsy_perform always returns error 7 (CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT).**
I re-checked whatever I thought may cause this error, but I couldn't resolve it. any idea? and my openssl is working on thread . i have Cross compile libcurl many time  . its a mipsel multicore architect

Answer (score 1):

`CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT` means libcurl fails to connect and establish a TCP connection to the host used in the URL. It is probably not related to it being multithreaded. Enable `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` and see if that gives you any more clues.